# Reading JSON response as a List of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get an object List from cors API but all of the List entries are `null`.

I succeeded in obtaining the List (list type and length are ok).

```
List<PluginModelDB> result;

using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiBroker.ApiClient.GetAsync(""))
{
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<PluginModelDB>>();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}

HomeViewModel.PluginList = new List<PluginModelDB>();

foreach (var p in result)
{
     HomeViewModel.PluginList.Add(new PluginModelDB { ID = p.ID, Name = p.Name, Description = p.Description});
}
```

Comment: maybe it's not able to deserialize properly. what's the value of `result`?

Comment: its a list that contains 2 empty objects of PluginModelDB

Comment: @MateuszFijak post the code that actualy deserializes the JSON string and the string itself. There's no `ReadAsAsync` in ASP.NET Core, where did it come from? Without knowing what the string and the classes look like, the only possible advice is to simply read the string and use JSON.NET to deserialize it.

Comment: From VladaxLe: `It seems that your model is not corresponds to received JSON. You can check you model via http://json2csharp.com/`

Comment: @MateuszFijak please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MateuszFijak if you think the community is at fault, consider how a tutor (or fellow students) would react if you asked them a question with missing vital information any useful info and then thanked the guy that *copied* their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your model is not corresponds to received JSON. You can check you model via http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

Comment: it was it, i had 2 models of the same thing and i run into name mismatch

Comment: @MateuszFijak no it wasn't. Update the question. Add the classes and the JSON string. The question is bad as it is and this is not an answer. In fact, the *other* answer is a much better one.

Comment: not really. it is better to get a small hint and figure the rest for myself rather than get a full answer ;)

Comment: @MateuszFijak that makes it a comment not an answer. SO is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 3):

Try to read it as string first, so  don't deserialize it immediately. Output that string to Console or a simple text file and see if you can track you items there. If not, the problem is at the API, its returning empty objects.

Comment: @MateuszFijak you skipped the important code. There's no `ApiBroker` in ASP.NET Core or `ReadAsAsync`. There used to be a legacy [System.Net.Http.Formatting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting) package with that method

Comment: seems like the API is doing wrong: [{"plugin":null},{"plugin":null}]

Comment: yup i had mistake in the API, actually i had DB and UI model, and their names did not match so it wasn't the same as JSON names, thanks for the hint